# SQL Server 2008: Host name did not change

Tags: sql-server-2008, upgrade

I have a SQL Server 2008 installation and I want to upgrade it to R2. During the upgrade process, in the **Reporting Services Authentication** window, the host name that appeared for the instance name is the previous name of my computer.

[image]

There error says:

```
Check whether report server is correctly configured, the database server is running, and you have permissions to access the database.
```

The database server can not be reached because of the wrong host name.

My current computer name is GS3-LNUBLA. LESTER-GS3 is the previous computer name. I can't go on the upgrade process because of this. Where can I change the host name to my current computer name?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you renamed the computer at some point after you installed SQL Server. If that's the case then take a look here regarding updating SQL Server with the new computer name:

http://strictlysql.blogspot.com/2010/03/changing-server-name.html

Comment: Hi. I have performed the steps in the link you gave me, but it seems not to take effect. The @@SERVERNAME has already changed, but the **instance of SQL Server that hosts the report server database** hasn't changed.